# Rename all csv files in folder by removing the end of the filename

Tags: python, pandas, csv, path, rename

I have an entire data folder ending with .csv.

All csv files are named like this :

- "data_AA_10_344362.csv"
- "data_AA_25_124567.csv"
- "data_AA_37_896432.csv"
- etc.

I want to rename all of them by removing everything after the **last** underscore but keep '.csv'.
So i would like my files to be renamed like this automatically :

- "data_AA_10.csv"
- "data_AA_25.csv"
- "data_AA_37.csv"

I've tried something like this but it's not complete/incorrect :

```
import glob, os
import pathlib
 
DATA_DIR = pathlib.Path('C:\\Users\\dvs\\documents\\data')

for old in DATA_DIR.glob('*.csv'):
    new = '_'.join(old.split('_')[:-1])
    os.rename(old, new)
```

I know this question has already been answered but i couldn't manage to do it on my own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
DATA_DIR = pathlib.Path('C:\\Users\\dvs\\documents\\data')

for old in DATA_DIR.glob('*.csv'):
    new = old.parent / f"{'_'.join(old.stem.split('_')[:-1])}{old.suffix}"
    old.rename(new)
    print(f'Renamed {old} to {new}')
```

Output (my data folder is 'cities')

```
Renamed cities/data_AA_25_124567.csv to cities/data_AA_25.csv
Renamed cities/data_AA_10_344362.csv to cities/data_AA_10.csv
Renamed cities/data_AA_37_896432.csv to cities/data_AA_37.csv
```

Answer (score 1):

Using .rename from pathlib:

```
from pathlib import Path


path = "C:\\Users\\dvs\\documents\\data"
[x.rename(f"{path}/{x.stem.rsplit('_', 1)[0]}.csv") for x in Path(path).rglob("*.csv")]
```